# Cutsom intent on independent Apple Watch app watchos6

Tags: apple-watch, sirikit, sirishortcuts, watchos-6, apple-watch-standalone

I'm building an independent Apple Watch App with a custom intent based Siri Shortcut. I am donating the shortcut whenever the corresponding action is used. I added it as an relevant Shortcut to the relevant Shortcut store. The code works just fine (I get a print confirmation whenever the Relevant Shortcut is created and added to the Relevant Shortcutstore), but it just does not show up on my Siri Watch face.

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Would love to get some help on this! This you ever figure it out?